# Error (10476): VHDL error at PEnc83.vhd(42): type of identifier "sy" does not agree with its usage as "std_ulogic" type

Tags: vhdl

I'm new to VHDL and I don't understand what is giving me the error:

```
Error (10476): VHDL error at PEnc83.vhd(42): type of identifier "sy" does not agree with its usage as "std_ulogic" type
```

This error also applies for "sz".

Here is my code:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity PEnc83 is
  port(I: in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
       O: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0);
       V: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR);
end PEnc83;

architecture arq_penc83 of PEnc83 is

  component PEnc421
    port(
      a: in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
      b: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
      v: out std_logic_vector);
  end component;

  component MUX2
    port(A, B: in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
         sel:  in  std_logic;
         O:    out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0));
  end component;


  SIGNAL sa, sx, sb : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  SIGNAL sy, sz : std_logic_vector;

Begin

  UPEnc1: PEnc421 port map (
    a => I,
    b => sa,
    v => sy);

  UPEnc2: PEnc421 port map (
    a => I,
    b => sx,
    v => sz);

  UPEnc3: PEnc421 port map (
    a(0) => sy,
    a(1) => sz,
    a(2) => '0',
    a(3) => '0',
    b => sb,
    v => V);

  UMUX2: MUX2 port map(
    A => sa,
    B => sx,
    sel => sb(2),
    O => O);

  O(2) <= sb(2);

end arq_penc83;
```

Since `sy` and `sz` are signals it should work like the other ones. But for some reason it just isn't, maybe is it because they are only 1 vector, but they are supposed to be only one vector that connects to PEnc3.

Comment: signals sy and sz are declared as unconstrained type std_logic_vector as well as in port formal declarations. The port map associations should provide a constraint via the actual associated with each formal and don't.

Comment: And check the widths of your vectors...

Answer (score 0):

Change line 42 to "a(0) => sy(0)", change line 43 in the same way. Then the compiler will probably accept your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors in your source:

1. If you mean a single bit, use `std_logic` instead of `std_logic_vector`. I interpreted all places without constraints (`( .. downto .. )`) as such.
2. If you want to connect only parts of a vector, you need to specify this. This is specifically necessary where you assign vectors of different widths.
3. Do not use indexes outside the constraints.
4. Presumably you became confused when you "wired" the multiplexer.

This is a corrected source, which does not produce syntax errors. However, it can have logical errors, because I don't know the logic you try to implement.

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity PEnc83 is
  port(I: in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
       O: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0);
       V: out STD_LOGIC);
end PEnc83;

architecture arq_penc83 of PEnc83 is

  component PEnc421
    port(
      a: in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
      b: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
      v: out std_logic);
  end component;

  component MUX2
    port(A, B: in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
         sel:  in  std_logic;
         O:    out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0));
  end component;


  SIGNAL sa, sx, sb : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  SIGNAL sc, sy, sz : std_logic;

Begin

  UPEnc1: PEnc421 port map (
    a => I(7 downto 4),
    b => sa,
    v => sy);

  UPEnc2: PEnc421 port map (
    a => I(3 downto 0),
    b => sx,
    v => sz);

  UPEnc3: PEnc421 port map (
    a(0) => sy,
    a(1) => sz,
    a(2) => '0',
    a(3) => '0',
    b => sb,
    v => V);

  UMUX2: MUX2 port map(
    A => sa,
    B => sx,
    sel => sb(0),
    O => O(1 downto 0));

  O(2) <= sc;

end arq_penc83;
```

Comment: *However, it can have logical errors, because I don't know the logic you try to implement.* And there is at least one other interpretation leading to code that can successfully be analyzed. [**Answer well-asked questions**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) "...avoid trying to answer questions which... •...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem." The question is unclear, you could have asked for further detail, the entity and architecture of PEnc421 may have sufficed (or revealed further problems).

Comment: The question was not about a _logical_ error, but a _syntactical_ error. This is answered, don't you think? But since my butt tells me that this might be a beginner, which easily falls into the trap that syntactical correctness means logical correctness, I added the warning.